# What is the best Latin translation of 'towards truth'?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary, word-request, word-comparison, word-choice

I am looking to create a Substack publication where I can share articles I have written on philosophy. I want to choose a name for the website that best summarises or encapsulates the nature of the subject.

A translation of 'truth'; 'towards truth'; 'of truth'; etc., is what I am currently considering. However, as this will form part of the website domain, I would like a title that is ideally one short word.

Although I was contemplating 'ad veritatem', I think 'veritati' offers a more memorable alternative.

I would like to know whether 'veritati' is accurate in the context of my publication or whether there are better alternatives or forms.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

ad veritatem would be the (too?) obvious choice

Comment: *Ad veritatem* is mentioned in the question. Can you elaborate on why you think it's the best choice? Bare answers are liable to be turned into comments.